"Pausing updating" Tactic state mid-sentence by a shortcut key or a setting in Lean 4 VSCode extension?
While entering Lean 4 proofs involving mathlib, I noticed that the Lean often get stuck in updating the Tactic state in Infoview while new characters are entered and the current command is not yet complete.
For example, when entering the apply, if I didn't type it quickly (or use autocomplete), Lean could get stuck when only the first two characters ap has been entered. It seems that Lean extension is too eager in refreshing the Infoview and is refreshing that state every time a new character is entered.
Sometimes the refresh catches up after five seconds, but often times, it gets stuck without finishing the update after hours.
Currently, I have to use the "Restart File" button to forcibly refresh the state if the automatic update hangs. But this is quite time-consuming.
In searching for a better solution, I noticed that:

In the very top right of the InfoView, there are three icon buttons:
...
Pause updating. Freezes the tactic state, expected type, messages and
widget sections. When frozen, the 'Pause updating' button is replaced
with a 'Continue updating' button. Can also be called using the
'Infoview: Toggle Updating' command.

It seems that I could hit the pause updating button before I enter a command and then hit the button again only after finishing the complete word or line.
But obviously, this can be slow too, as I'll need to switch between the mouse and keyboard very frequently.
Is there a a shortcut key to toggle updating in the VSCode extension (or a way to add a shortcut key for this)?
Or even better,
Is there a way to configure the lean extension to only update the state after a complete word or line is entered (instead of on each new character)?

Not what you are asking, but by chance, did you make sure to download the mathlib cache (lake exe cache get)?  Otherwise, it could be checking all of mathlib in the background.

@JasonRute Thanks. Yes, I did run lake exe get and also tried the route the let vscode "recompile" .lake/ in the project folder. Either way, it's 4.8G in size. Now the version I am testing is based on lake exe get. The state update is some times successful in seconds and sometimes hangs (about half-half split).

Do you have autosaving enabled? On Windows there was an issue where autosaving could lead to really bad performance. It's supposed to have been fixed, but I'm not sure if it's in the newest Lean 4 extension release or not yet.
